# PTO request shows on calendar for all users

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow

I have a MS Forms + Flow created that pulls the info from the Form and creates an entry on our PTO Calendar.  However, during testing, only the person who created the PTO Request can view the entry on the calendar.  Everyone else (mainly the company admin) can't view the entry.

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the calendar, under list settings / advanced, check out the Item Level Permissions section and make sure that Read Items That Were Created By The User is not selected, and Read All Items is selected.